# Can ANCOVA be used to control for lengths of treatment?

Tags: ancova

I have the same treatment I administered to two groups (experimentals and controls). (This is a hypothetical study asked by one of my students.) The experimental group received the treatment for 6 weeks, the control group for 8 weeks. Means of the dependent variable obviously favored the control condition. Can I run ANCOVA to compare effects and covary the number of treatment weeks, or is there a better way to compare the effects of the treatment? Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

If the response is taken only at the end of the study, the treatment (experimental vs. control) is completely confounded with the duration. Unless I misunderstand it, it is not a crossed design, so n=0 to check for the interaction between the two factors. If both trt groups had 6 and 8 weeks durations, you could have done a two-way ANOVA (with trt and duration as factors), whereas ANCoVA is best suited for continuous covariates. If, however, response variables were taken at multiple points during the study, you could attempt a rmANOVA, dropping the non-matching datapoints.